# Putting Pictures in DynamoDB

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, amazon-dynamodb

I was wondering if it was possible to put pictures into DynamoDB tables from an iOS device. If so I was wondering if someone could provide me with an example using the Swift language as I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB supports attributes of Binary type. You could have an IMAGES table where you store items with an image Binary attribute value. The maximum item size of DynamoDB items is 400KB. If the images you are trying to store are larger, or can be larger than 400KB, then you will not be able to store those images. In case you want to support images larger than 400KB, store S3 links to the images in DynamoDB, and store the actual images in S3. It might be easier to only store links to images in S3.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible if the images are small enough - better answer: don't do it. Just because you could, doesn't mean you should.

If you are working in/on the amazon stack, s3 is a much better place to store images.